# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

No se porqué me dice que el objeto no es invocable, estoy haciendo los pasos del libro:

```
<Caja>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: 600, 400
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Iniciar'
            on_release: camera.play = True
        Button:
            text: 'Capturar'
            on_press: root.capturar()
        Button:
            text: 'Parar'
            on_release: camera.play = False
        Button:
            text: 'Cerrar'
            on_release:root.stop()
```

Éste es mi código:

```
import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
class Camara(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        file_name = "capturado" + time.strtime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png(file_name+".png")
class Plantilla(App):
    def build(self):
        return Camara()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Plantilla().run()
```

El .kv:

```
<Camara>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: 600, 400
        play: False
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Iniciar'
            on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
            height: '20dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Capturar'
            on_press: root.capture()
        Button:
            text: 'Parar'
            on_release: camera.play = False
        Button:
            text: 'Cerrar'
            on_release:root.stop()
```

Comment: Hola Héctor, en cuanto a tu problema, ¿podrías agregar la traza completa del error? He revisado tu código y hay dos errores, no existe `time.strtime()`, es `time.strftime()`, supongo que es solo un typo. Por otro lado, en el .kv, tampoco existe `root.stop()` (AKA `Camara.stop()`), si quieres cerrar la aplicación debe ser `app.stop()`. Con ésto, no lo he probado, pero debe funcionar a la perfección, no veo por dónde puede salir un `None()` que es la causa del error que muestras...

Comment: Entendido, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestarme, voy a subir el error completo.

Comment: Lo siento, me tarde mi laptop por alguna razon dejo de funcionar pero ya la tengo de nuevo en linea aqui esta lo que me pediste:

Comment: Hola mira hice de nuevo la pregunta le agregue una imagen aqui esta el enlace (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359306/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-callable-ayuda)